# Android: Is it possible to detect if user hanged up call or callee?

Tags: android, phone-call

I know there are similar questions like mine, but they are pretty old. I hope there is some solution to this problem.

One of my clients wants the application to be able to detect if the call was hanged up by the caller or the callee? Can someone tell me if this is possible or just tell me that it's impossible to do it at all?

I thought about to detect if the user pressed the hang-up button while in a call, but I don't know if that is possible to detect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar question like you that I want an event that receiver receives the call.I had searched on net and I knew that You can not get any event that receiver receives the phone.