# Android: detect if user hung up call or callee?

Tags: android, freeze, phone-call, disconnect

My android app makes outgoing call:

```
        Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:12345678900));
        startActivity(dial);
```

After that user (caller) or callee can hang up.
How can I detect who hung up caller or callee?
I've seen the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577498/androidis-it-possible-to-detect-if-user-hanged-up-call-or-callee)  but there are not a positive answer, only negative and it was 4 years ago.

I can't believe that it's impossible. 
I tried to use BroadcastReceiver, PhoneStateListener, CallLog. It's helped to detect type of call: outgoing or incoming call, answered or unanswered call but it hasn't helped to detect who hung up caller or callee.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy you need to have a broadcast receiver which listens for an intent call hangup or in technical terms `TELEPHONYMANAGER.EXTRA_STATE_OFHOOK`

If required you can also check if the number was the number you dialed to. If you require any additional code etc. Comment below and I'll help.

Comment: As I know that Broadcast receiver can only help to detect when the call began and ended but it can't help to detect who hung up caller or callee. May be I don't know something. If so clarify me please with some example.